# Let $f(x)=2e^x + (a^2-5a+6)e^{-x} + (10a-2a^2-11)x - 3$ is increasing on values of $x$, then find number of integral values of $a$

Tags: functions

The given solutions involves a kinda hard to notice manipulation shown as follows

$$f'(x)=2e^x-(a^2-5a+6)e^{-x} + (10a-2a^2 -11)$$
$$=2e^{-x}[e^x + (5a-a^2-6)][e^x + \frac 12]$$
$$\implies 2\le a \le 3$$

Now A different method i came across was to set $a^2-5a+6<0$  and $-2a^2+10a-11>0$ ie. turning all terms in the expression positive. This gives $1.633 < a < 3.366$ ie. $2 \le a \le 3$

This gives the same answer but i am worried about its validity, ie will it give extraneous roots or omit some important roots in other case, and was this just a happy accident ?

Comment: In the second approach, the function is increasing ...  but it is not shown that it is NOT increasing for a different choice of $a.$

Comment: @user376343 so what does that imply?

Comment: It implies this: It could occur that certain solution(s) are not found by the second method.

Comment: @user376343 so just got lucky in this car